# Powershell RegEx match negative lookbehind at start of string

Tags: regex, powershell, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I'm currently working on a WSUS-Update automization and I'd like to get all Updates that don't start with "(German|English) Language Pack".

This is what I got so far:

```
[regex]$reg = "(?<!German|English|English \(United States\)) Language Pack"
$LanguagePacks = $updates.Where({ $_.Title -match $reg })
```

That works, but I also get updates like:
Windows Internet Explorer 9 Language Pack for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems

But I also want to get Updates in the following syntax:
[Language] Language Pack e.g. Finnish Language Pack

So I tried to use the '^' anchor to determine the start of the String

```
[regex]$reg = "^(?<!German|English|English \(United States\)) Language Pack"
$LanguagePacks = $updates.Where({ $_.Title -match $reg })
```

But in this case the result is empty :(

Comment: could you give a sample text

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<!^(?:German|English(?:\s+\(United States\))?)\s*)Language Pack
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5E%28%3F%3AGerman%7CEnglish%28%3F%3A%5Cs%2B%5C%28United%20States%5C%29%29%3F%29%5Cs*%29Language%20Pack&i=Windows%20Internet%20Explorer%209%20Language%20Pack%20for%20Windows%207%20for%20x64-based%20Systems%0D%0A%0D%0AFinnish%20Language%20Pack%0D%0A%0D%0AGerman%20Language%20Pack%0D%0AEnglish%20Language%20Pack%0D%0A&o=m)

It matches `Language Pack` if it is not preceded with `German`, `English`, or `English (United States)` at the start of the string.

**Details**

- `(?<!` - start of a negative lookbehind that fails the match if, immediately to the left of the current location, there are patterns:

  - `^` - start of string
  - `(?:` - start of an alternation non-capturing group:

    - `German` - a literal substring
    - `|` - or
    - `English`  - a literal substring
    - `(?:\s+\(United States\))?` - an optional non-capturing group matches 1 or 0 occurrences of:

      - `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
      - `\(United States\)` - a literal `(United States)` substring
  - `)` - end of the alternation group
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `)` - end of the lookbehind
- `Language Pack`  - a literal substring